# JavaFX Intellij idea

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea, jvm

После создание джарника javafx даблкликом ничего не происходит. Попробовал через батник пишет
Error: Could not find or load main class sample.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
Хотя если запускать джарник из idea то всё работает. В чём может быть причина господа?

Answer (score 0):

Я сам сталкивался с многими ошибками при согдании jar файла, с приложением сделанном на JavaFX.
Ошибку такого рода я решил добавив сласс Main2, написав туда:

```
public class Main2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main.main(args);
    }
}
```

Если класс Main2 есть, то проверьте файл jar:

1. Откройте jar с помощью 7zip или WinRAR.
2. Откройте папку META-INF (если нет, то создайте)
3. После чего откройте (можно блокнотом) MANIFEST.MF и проверьте что бы там было написанно: `Main-Class:`
   Что показывает файлу jar класс, который будет грузиться (стандарный класс).

Я сам работаю в Intellij idea и он автоматом делает:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.example.asd.Main2
```

Обязательно ссылку на класс Main2, иначе будет ошибка:

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

В файле MANIFEST.MF, если вы работаете в Intellij idea, то ссылка на класс будет одинаковая для всех, этот файл будет выглядеть так:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.example.НАЗВАНИЕ ВАШЕГО ПРОЕКТА.Main2
```

НАЗВАНИЕ ВАШЕГО ПРОЕКТА можно скопировать нажав на выделенную дерикторию:

[image]

Где asd (как у меня), это название проекта.
Ошибки с jar это отдельная тема, они иногда "возникают Из ниоткуда", надеюсь мой ответ помог вам.

PS: класс можно названь и не Main2 это название для меня.

Comment: Спасибо, но с такой колхозной совместимостью версий перешёл на swing и забыл про это недоразумение